# Schur-convexity of multinomial distribution

Tags: statistics, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider $\{p_i \in [0,c]\}_i$, $c<1$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i = P$ for some positive $k>2$ and constant $P < 1$. Let $(x_i \in \mathbb{N})_i$. Is 
$$f(p_1,\ldots,p_k)
= \sum_{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k=0}^{c} \frac{p_1^{x_1}}{x_1} \frac{p_2^{x_2}}{x_2!}
\cdots
\frac{p_k^{x_k}}{x_k!}
$$
Schur-concave in $\{p_i\}$? 
The function is symmetric, but it is a bit hard to check the cond $\partial f/\partial p_i - \partial f/\partial p_j$. Any suggestion?

PS: The function is similar to the marginal of a [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? Positive or also negative input?

Comment: edited the question accordingly. $\{p_i\}'s$ are probability simplex.

Comment: then the answer is trivial, right?

Comment: you were right. Actually, it should be Schur-concave, and also I had a summation, which was missing in the original question. Now, it is not trivial to me whether it is Schur-concave or not...